# Source of an Asimov quotation about the citadel of truth

Tags: quote-source, isaac-asimov

Somewhere Isaac Asimov remarks that the citadel of truth can only be breached by a brute-force assault. I would like the exact source of this quote.

Comment: I can't even find anybody quoting Asimov with the words "citadel of truth".